# What is the difference between a declarator and a direct-declarator?

Tags: c, syntax, programming-languages, declaration, variable-declaration

In *The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition,* by authors Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, they talk about *declarators* and *direct-declarators*. The discussion starts in the book on p. 122 with *dcl* and *direct-dcl*'s Will you please explain the difference between a declarator and a direct-declarator in and easy to understand way? What makes it *direct*?

Also, on p. 225

> where the direct-declarator is an identifier or a parenthesized identifier. In particular, it must not achieve function type by means of a typedef.

It seems to me that declarators are the declaration of a variable or function. In "T D", the T part specifies its specifiers and types, and the D part specifies the identity, meaning the unique identification name of the variable or function. It has something to do with the language's grammar.

Are *declarator*s indirect since they are not specified as direct, as in *direct-declarator*?

Comment: See the syntax diagram [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6)

Comment: The distinction is really only important for parsing declarations, they're not really distinct concepts in the language. The term "direct-declarator" never appears outside the syntax diagram

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. Your diagram may be helpful when I'm more familiar with the topic, but I don't understand the syntax diagram, and it doesn't explain the difference between a *declarator* and a *direct-declarator*.
Also, I want to understand the grammar. I'm a Computer Science student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar needs a *direct-declarator* token to specify precedence. As it is, `* foo [ 3 ]` must be parsed as a *declarator* that is `*` followed by a *direct-declarator* that is `foo [ 3 ]`. If the grammar did not separate a *declarator* and a *direct-declarator*, it could be unclear whether this was `*` followed by `foo [ 3 ]` grouped together or was `* foo` grouped together followed by `[ 3 ]`.

The grammar says a *declarator* is:

- *pointer*<sub>opt</sub> *direct-declarator*

where *pointer* is `*` followed by optional qualifiers (like `const`) and *direct-declarator* is one of:

- *identifier*
- `(` *declarator* `)`
- *direct-declarator* `[` *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> *assignment-expression*<sub>opt</sub> `]`
- *direct-declarator* `[` `static` *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> *assignment-expression* `]`
- *direct-declarator* `[` *type-qualifier-list* `static` *assignment-expression* `]`
- *direct-declarator* `[` *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> * `]`
- *direct-declarator* `(` *parameter-type-list* `)`
- *direct-declarator* `(` *identifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)`

So, given `* foo [ 3 ]`, we must take this as a declarator with `*` for *pointer* and `foo [ 3 ]` for *direct-declarator*. There is no way to have `*` at the start of a *direct-declarator*. Thus, `* foo [ 3 ]` must declare an array of 3 pointers, not a pointer to an array of 3 elements.

If those options for *declarator* and *direct-declarator* were merged into a single grammar token, then the parsing would be ambiguous. You could parse it as `* foo [ 3 ]` being that `* foo` is a declarator followed by `[ 3 ]`, which is not what we desire.

The name is of no great significance; we merely need another name for the additional token. There are other examples of this in the C grammar. Notably, the expressions grammar starts with *expression* and then goes through a chain of *assignment-expression*, *conditional-expression*, *logical-OR-expression*, and so on. These have names associated with the operators they involve, until you get to *primary-expression*. That has some semantic similarity to *direct-declarator*, suggesting they are both named in the spirit of “okay, we got to the bottom of this grammar chain, here is the primary/direct token.”

Comment: This really helped: "That has some semantic similarity to direct-declarator, suggesting they are both named in the spirit of “okay, we got to the bottom of this grammar chain, here is the primary/direct token.”"

Answer (score 4):

Even the second edition of K&R is more of historical interest these days than practical interest.

Nevertheless, the terms "declarator" and "direct declarator" continue in use in the current C language specification.  The language spec describes the former this way:

> Each declarator declares one identifier, and asserts that when an operand of the same form as the declarator appears in an expression, it designates a function or object with the scope, storage duration, and type indicated by the declaration specifiers.

(C17 6.7.6/2)

It follows that "declaration specifiers" are separate from "declarators".  In fact, a declarator is the part of a declaration that specifies *what* is being declared.

"Direct declarators" is a subset of declarators.  The "direct" is meant to contrast with "indirect", as in pointers.  For example, given

```
int i;
int *p;
```

The `i` and `*p` and `p` are all syntactically declarators, but of those, only `i` and `p` are *direct* declarators.  And only `i` and `*p` are *full* declarators, which are those that do not appear as part of another declarator (as declarator `p` does).

It gets more complicated than that -- for example, enclosing *any* declarator in parentheses yields a direct declarator, even if by itself, the original declarator is not a direct one.

Overall, this is a syntactic distinction that you probably don't need to worry too much about unless you are writing a parser for the C language.  And if you *are* doing that, then you really need to be looking at the formal syntax descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

Loosely speaking, a **declarator** is a complete declaration, while a **direct declarator** is either an identifier by itself or an identifier followed by `[]` (making it an array) or `()` (making a function or function pointer).

The complete definition of these terms can be found in the syntax for a declarator which can be found in section 6.7.6p1 of the [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> declarator:
>
> - pointer<sub>opt</sub> direct-declarator
>
> direct-declarator:
>
> - identifier
> - `(` declarator `)`
> - direct-declarator `[` type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> assignment-expression<sub>opt</sub> `]`
> - direct-declarator `[` `static` type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> assignment-expression `]`
> - direct-declarator `[` type-qualifier-list `static` assignment-expression `]`
> - direct-declarator `[` type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> `*` `]`
> - direct-declarator `(` parameter-type-list `)`
> - direct-declarator `(` identifier-list<sub>opt</sub> `)`
>
> pointer:
>
> - `*` type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub>
> - `*` type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> pointer
>
> type-qualifier-list:
>
> - type-qualifier
> - type-qualifier-list type-qualifier
>
> parameter-type-list:
>
> - parameter-list
> - parameter-list `,` `...`
>
> parameter-list:
>
> - parameter-declaration
> - parameter-list `,` parameter-declaration
>
> parameter-declaration:
>
> - declaration-specifiers declarator
> - declaration-specifiers abstract-declarator<sub>opt</sub>